# c++ receive const lvalue and rvalue reference parameter without overload

Tags: c++, c++11

```
void f(const std::vector<int>& v)  //#1
{
    std::vector<int> a(v);
    ...
}
void f(std::vector<int>&& v)       //#2
{
    std::vector<int> a(std::move(v));
    ...
}
```

Is there some way to write #1 and #2 in one function without overloading but achieving the same effect? I mean, if argument is lvalue, then use copy constructor, if argument is rvalue, then use move constructor.

As you can see, if there is more than one parameter, I will need to write 2^n overloads.

Comment: If both overloads do the same thing, drop the second one. If they don't, you can use some template magic but that is really unnecessary, and in some cases doesn't work (constructors, assignment operators for example).

Comment: I mean, you can pass the `A` by value instead, which will have basically the same effect as #2 (the value would be move-constructed) but would perform an unnecessary copy in the case of #1.

Comment: something like that  for template magic: `template <typename T> std::enable_it_t<std::is_same<A, std::decay_t<T>>::value> f(T&&);`

Comment: @Jarod42 you're over-constraining the function. Put `std::is_base_of<A, std::decay_t<T>>`

Comment: Thank you all for response. I have edited the question and made it clearer.

Comment: afaik, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward could be the answer

Comment: If you are making a copy anyway, just pass by value.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need both! Using forwarding you could just as easily write:

```
template < typename T >
void f(T&& t)
{
  std::vector<int> v(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

And then all these following calls would work:

```
std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3 };
f(std::move(a));
f(a);

const std::vector<int> b = { 1, 2, 3 };
f(b);
```

Comment: This is not a forwarding reference

Comment: @NathanOliver, you are right. Fixed the implementation.

Comment: `f(std::move(b));` -- what's `b`? You haven't declared it.

Comment: @cdhowie, thanks, copy paste mistake

Comment: Okay, but what's the purpose of calling `std::move` on a const object? What use do we have for a `const std::vector<int> &&` here?

Comment: @cdhowie, std::move retains constness, so you could call it with or without it. I updated my solution to show that.

Comment: Sure, I just don't particularly see the point here... in `f()` the constructor overload chosen should be `const vector&`, so the "move" isn't really moving anything.

Comment: @cdhowie, I put it there to show that all combination work, but since there is really no point in moving a const var, I removed it.